# Porque quando eu clico no botão não calcula?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma calculadora simples com *Javacript* e quando eu digito os valores nos `input` ele são agrupados e não somados o que estou fazendo de errado? segue o código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="text">calcular</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
    
        var input1 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
        var input2 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
        var button = window.document.querySelector("button");
    
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.document.querySelector("p").textContent = input1.value + input2.value;
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não tá fazendo nada de errado o problema é de lógica, pois o que vem de um `input` é texto é `string` e não número `number`, então o que você tem que fazer é simplesmente converter o valor que vem do `input` que é `string` para `number`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="text">calcular</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
    
        var input1 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
        var input2 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
        var button = window.document.querySelector("button");
    
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.document.querySelector("p").textContent = Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isto está acontecendo porque `input1.value` e `input2.value` são strings, portanto, o que você está fazendo é somando duas strings.

Para solucionar este problema, é necessário converter o `value` para number. Assim:

```
window.document.querySelector("p").textContent = Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Só o que faltou foi converter os valores do inputs para numérico. Perceba que o input está como tipo `"text"`, mesmo se você utilizar o tipo `"number"` o JavaScript ainda lerá como texto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="text">calcular</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
    
        var input1 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
        var input2 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
        var button = window.document.querySelector("button");
    
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.document.querySelector("p").textContent = Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo com type `"number"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number">
    <input type="number">
    <button type="text">calcular</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
    
        var input1 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
        var input2 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
        var button = window.document.querySelector("button");
    
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.document.querySelector("p").textContent = input1.value + input2.value;
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```